# Paypal add-on not showing venmo and other payment buttons in gravity form

Tags: wordpress, paypal, gravity-forms-plugin, venmo

I am using paypal extension in gravity forms but It is not showing “venmo” and “debit or credit card” buttons please check the screenshot.

[image]

But according to the setting/configuration provided by gravity forms docs https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_ppcp_enable_funding/

It should look like this

[image]

I have tried out the solutions provided in the forums for example here

https://community.gravityforms.com/t/paypal-checkout-venmo-button-not-appearing/14555

I have applied the solution(add_filter) mentioned in document https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_ppcp_enable_funding/

But still venmo and card buttons are not showing. Can any one help please?